# Moving scripted games to other sites

Tags: javascript, html, flash, weebly

I have a website (rhettr.weebly.com) and I am wanting to add [this game](http://www.letsplaysnes.com/emulation/emu.php?domain=www.letsplaysnes.com&userid=&emu=SNES&disRAM=http://www.letsplaysnes.com/play-the-legend-of-zelda-a-link-to-the-past-online/?&altRAM=&rom=http://www.letsplaysnes.com/roms/The_Legend_of_Zelda_-_A_Link_to_the_Past.zip). I am doing this for school so it has to be unblocked, I know how to upload .swf files but when I look for a .swf it just has "script source" instead of the flash application script. the script source link is

```
box.anchorfree.net/insert/insert.php?sn=HSSHIELD00US&ch=HSSCNL000553&v=6331615266&b=c&ver=us&afver=3.19
```

But i need to find a way to upload it to my weebly website. On weebly I can upload .swf and HTML but I don't know what the HTML option does. If you find out question 1 please help on this game being ported to [my site too](http://www.totaljerkface.com/happy_wheels.tjf).

Comment: Weebly has restrictions on what you can upload, and what you can do with it once it has been uploaded.

Comment: Thanks i understand, but how would i do it if weebly had no restrictions, and can i not use the HTML option to upload it?

Comment: like how does totaljerkface.com import the full version of Happy Wheels?

Comment: "Remember I am doing this for school so it has to be unblocked,"
Maybe you should pay attention in class instead. Perhaps then you will learn how to code it into your html. :)

Comment: I know you are trying to be the hero here and unblock games for your friends. But there are already plenty of unblocked sites out there. [This one](http://unblocked-games-4-u.weebly.com/games.html) is my favorite. And here is your [Happy Wheels](http://unblocked-games-4u.weebly.com/happy-wheels.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code to your site:

```
<iframe src="http://www.letsplaysnes.com/emulation/emu.php?domain=www.letsplaysnes.com&userid=&emu=SNES&disRAM=http://www.letsplaysnes.com/play-the-legend-of-zelda-a-link-to-the-past-online/?&altRAM=&rom=http://www.letsplaysnes.com/roms/The_Legend_of_Zelda_-_A_Link_to_the_Past.zip" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

And for Happy Wheels:

```
<iframe src="http://unblocked-games-4u.weebly.com/happy-wheels.html" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

This creates an [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) You can set the width and height to whatever you want, I am pretty sure though that they block `<iframe>`'s to specific web pages.

**Another alternative**

You can try paying attention and doing you work. And then play games when you get home or some other time.

Comment: WOW IT WORKED!!!!!! Now can you help with: http://www.totaljerkface.com/happy_wheels.tjf

Comment: Okay I added happy Wheels. And if it worked please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: when i do the happy wheels one it shows me the website inside the iframe, and shows everything exept the game inside it. If you inspect element it it shows the script written directly into the page

Comment: Hmmm that is weird. It could be that your school just blocked it.

Comment: no actually im at my house working on it. It is a cracked, full version game that they ported onto their site, I really want to add it. P.S. will that iframe be blocked at school, and will it work?

Comment: we use lightspeed i have tried everything, i have tried adding HTTPS and proxies. I love the Hotspot Shield proxy but not everyone at school is going to get it just to play one game:(

Comment: we use lightspeed i have tried everything, i have tried adding HTTPS and proxies. I love the Hotspot Shield proxy but not everyone at school is going to get it just to play one game:(

Comment: I just want to know how they ported the happy wheels game, i want too but i dont know if its possible for 1 person to work on

Comment: Oh, I have no idea how the ported it. But try the second iframe again. The one with the link to Happy Wheels. Maybe it will work this time...

Comment: I know how to get the demo, but i want the full version only off totaljerkface.com

Comment: I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put it in an iframe modifying the url to get the ROM from your site

Comment: I have not idea how to do code, I know how to find the .swf's from code but i dont know how to actually add stuff

Comment: then you should read this to get some directions on the usage of the <iframe> tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: would i be asking to much for you to give me an example....thanks if yes if no thanks for your help